# not able to deploy android build to GIT repository through Maven Android Plugin

Tags: android, git, maven, github

I am trying to deploy my android project to Git repository using Maven-Android-Plugin. However while deploying I am getting an error like:

> ***Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not find artifact com.example:asynctasksample:apk:1.0-20130110.120545-1 in github
>   (https://github.com/rlsahu/AndroidPOC)***

Please have a look to the following for more details:

```
     F:\Android\AsyncTaskSample>mvn deploy
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building asynctasksample 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- android-maven-plugin:3.5.0:generate-sources (default-generate-sources) @ asynctasksample ---
[INFO] ANDROID-904-002: Found aidl files: Count = 0
[INFO] ANDROID-904-002: Found aidl files: Count = 0
[INFO] Manifest merging disabled. Using project manifest only
[INFO] E:\Nitin\Android-SDK\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\aapt.exe [package, -m, -J, F:\Android\AsyncTaskSample\target\generated-sources\r, -M, F:\Android\AsyncTaskSample\AndroidManifest.xml, -S, F:\Android\AsyncTaskSample\res, --auto-add-overlay, -A, F:\Android\AsyncTaskSample\assets, -I, E:\Nitin\Android-SDK\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-10\android.jar]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ asynctasksample ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory F:\Android\AsyncTaskSample\src\main\resources
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory F:\Android\AsyncTaskSample\target\generated-sources\extracted-dependencies\src\main\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile (default-compile) @ asynctasksample ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 3 source files to F:\Android\AsyncTaskSample\target\classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- android-maven-plugin:3.5.0:proguard (default-proguard) @ asynctasksample ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ asynctasksample ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory F:\Android\AsyncTaskSample\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ asynctasksample ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.13:test (default-test) @ asynctasksample ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- android-maven-plugin:3.5.0:emma (default-emma) @ asynctasksample ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- android-maven-plugin:3.5.0:dex (default-dex) @ asynctasksample ---
[INFO] C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_18\jre\bin\java [-Xmx1024M, -jar, E:\Nitin\Android-SDK\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\lib\dx.jar, --dex, --output=F:\Android\AsyncTaskSample\target\classes.dex, F:\Android\AsyncTaskSample\target\classes]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ asynctasksample ---
[INFO] Building jar: F:\Android\AsyncTaskSample\target\AndroidPOC.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- android-maven-plugin:3.5.0:apk (default-apk) @ asynctasksample ---
[INFO] Copying local assets files to combined assets directory.
[INFO] Enabling debug build for apk.
[INFO] E:\Nitin\Android-SDK\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\aapt.exe [package, -f, -M, F:\Android\AsyncTaskSample\AndroidManifest.xml, -S, F:\Android\AsyncTaskSample\res, --auto-add-overlay, -A, F:\Android\AsyncTaskSample\target\generated-sources\combined-assets\assets, -I, E:\Nitin\Android-SDK\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-10\android.jar, -F, F:\Android\AsyncTaskSample\target\AndroidPOC.ap_, --debug-mode]
[INFO] Add native libraries from F:\Android\AsyncTaskSample\libs
[INFO]
[INFO] --- android-maven-plugin:3.5.0:internal-pre-integration-test (default-internal-pre-integration-test) @ asynctasksample ---
[INFO] No InstrumentationRunner found - skipping tests
[INFO]
[INFO] --- android-maven-plugin:3.5.0:internal-integration-test (default-internal-integration-test) @ asynctasksample ---
[INFO] No InstrumentationRunner found - skipping tests
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ asynctasksample ---
[INFO] Installing F:\Android\AsyncTaskSample\target\AndroidPOC.apk to C:\Users\rsahu\.m2\repository\com\example\asynctasksample\1.0-SNAPSHOT\asynctasksample-1.0-SNAPSHOT.apk
[INFO] Installing F:\Android\AsyncTaskSample\pom.xml to C:\Users\rsahu\.m2\repository\com\example\asynctasksample\1.0-SNAPSHOT\asynctasksample-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] Installing F:\Android\AsyncTaskSample\target\AndroidPOC.jar to C:\Users\rsahu\.m2\repository\com\example\asynctasksample\1.0-SNAPSHOT\asynctasksample-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- downloads-maven-plugin:0.6:upload (default) @ asynctasksample ---
[INFO] Adding 1 download to repository rlsahu/AndroidPOC
[INFO] Deleting existing download: AndroidPOC.apk (id=392972)
[INFO] Adding download: AndroidPOC.apk (24,789 bytes)
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) @ asynctasksample ---
Downloading: https://github.com/rlsahu/AndroidPOC/com/example/asynctasksample/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Uploading: https://github.com/rlsahu/AndroidPOC/com/example/asynctasksample/1.0-SNAPSHOT/asynctasksample-1.0-20130110.120545-1.apk
Uploading: https://github.com/rlsahu/AndroidPOC/com/example/asynctasksample/1.0-SNAPSHOT/asynctasksample-1.0-20130110.120545-1.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 24.513s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Jan 10 17:35:49 IST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/29M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project asynctasksample: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not find artifact com.example:asynctasksample:apk:1.0-20130110.120545-1 in github (https://github.com/rlsahu/AndroidPOC) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
F:\Android\AsyncTaskSample>
```

My pom.xml file is as follows:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>asynctasksample</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>apk</packaging>

    <issueManagement>
        <url>https://github.com/rlsahu/AndroidPOC/issues</url>
        <system>GitHub Issues</system>
    </issueManagement>


    <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
      <id>github</id>
      <name>Android POC</name>
      <url>https://github.com/rlsahu/AndroidPOC</url>
    </repository>
  </distributionManagement>

    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>MIT License</name>
            <url>http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php</url>
            <distribution>repo</distribution>
        </license>
    </licenses>

    <scm>
        <url>https://github.com/rlsahu/AndroidPOC</url>
        <connection>scm:git:git://github.com/rlsahu/AndroidPOC.git</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:rlsahu/AndroidPOC.git</developerConnection>
    </scm>

    <developers>
        <developer>
            <email>rsahu@cybage.com</email>
            <url>https://github.com/rlsahu</url>
            <id>rlsahu</id>
        </developer>
    </developers>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <github.global.server>github</github.global.server>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>1.6_r2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>AndroidPOC</finalName>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.5.0</version>

                    <extensions>true</extensions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <override>true</override>
                    <sdk>
                        <!-- platform or api level (api level 4 = platform 1.6)-->
                        <platform>10</platform>
                    </sdk>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.github</groupId>
                <artifactId>downloads-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.6</version>

                <configuration>
                    <override>true</override>
                    <message>Building site for ${project.version}</message>
                    <server>github</server>
                </configuration>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>upload</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.github</groupId>
                <artifactId>site-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <override>true</override>
                    <message>Building site for ${project.version}</message>
                    <server>AndroidPOC</server>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>site</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>site</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>           
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Please provide your suggestion by looking into the above. Thanks.